# template const / non const method

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, code-duplication

Suppose we have code like this:

```
template<class CALLBACK>
struct INIFile{
    INIFile(CALLBACK &processor) :
                    processor(processor     ){}

    bool process(){
        // lots of code here,
        // call processor
        processor(123);

        return true;
    }

    CALLBACK    &processor;
};


struct MyProcessor{
    void operator()(int val){
        // do something
    }
};

struct MyConstProcessor{
    void operator()(int val) const{ // !!!!!
        // do something
    }
};

int main(){
    MyProcessor p;
    INIFile<MyProcessor> ini(p);
    ini.process();

    // const case:
    MyConstProcessor cp;
    INIFile<MyConstProcessor> cini(cp);
    cini.process();
}
```

In both cases `INIFile<>::process()` will be a non `const` member function.

Is there an easy way to make `process()` a `const` member function if `CALLBACK::operator()` is `const`, without duplicate all logic in `INIFile<>::process()`?

Comment: Contrary to `noexcept`, there are no `const(condition)` qualifier.

Comment: @NathanOliver: OP would like to have `INIFile<MyProcessor>::process()` and `INIFile<MyConstProcessor>::process() const` without to have to duplicate code.

Comment: @Jarod42 exactly my point. but is there any tricks? I have some ideas, like extracting "lots of code here" into const function, but it have several branches and result non duplicated code is way too complicated

Comment: Ah.  Okay.  So you want `process()` to be `const` if `CALLBACK::operator()` is `const`.

Comment: @NathanOliver exactly. please feel free to edit the question

Comment: @Nick Edited.  Fell free to roll back if you think that changes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is solved by doing the following:

```
template<class CALLBACK>
struct INIFile{
    INIFile(CALLBACK &processor) :
                    processor(processor){}

    template <class T>
    bool process_impl(T& processor) const {
        // deliberately shadow processor
        // reduce likelihood of using member processor, but can use other member variables

        // lots of code
        processor(123);
        return true;
    }

    bool process() const {
        return process_impl(const_cast<const CALLBACK&>(processor));
    }
    bool process() {
        return process_impl(processor);
    }

    CALLBACK&    processor;
};
```

This of course technically overloads `process`, but it has the exact same effect that you want. If the `processor`'s call operator is *not* marked const, and you try to call `process` via a const reference or const copy of the object, you get a compilation error (unlike with your solution). That's because the `const` overload of `process` gets called, it adds the `const` to the processor which gets passed along, and then of course the call operator on the processor fails.

However, if the callback does provide a `const` call operator, then either process call will do exactly the same thing. This effectively means that you can call `process` on a const copy of `INIFile`, which is equivalent to `process` being `const`.

If the callback also overloads the call operator, then this implementation will forward along to whichever is correct, but you didn't specify that as a condition. The only thing to watch out for, is that `process_impl` should never access the member variable `processor`, because that member variable will always be mutable, i.e. the call will work even when it shouldn't (like in your solution). I shadow intentionally to try to prevent this. This isn't that beautiful but as an implementation detail it's not so bad, and it does remove the duplication.

Comment: Nice solution, but is there any reason to use `const_cast` instead of `static_cast`?? Isn't it just `CALLBACK&` -> `const CALLBACK&`. Or is it just one letter less to type :)

Comment: I guess in this situation there is no real reason because it would be hard to imagine how you could make a mistake either way; you are clearly adding const-ness and you clearly would have to work hard to get the wrong type.

Comment: amazing usage of sfinae

Answer (score 0):

Another way I found, but I do not like it very much is to use pointer instead of reference.

Here is the code.

Note in this particular case we do not need to check for `nullptr` at all.

```
template<class CALLBACK>
struct INIFile{
    INIFile(CALLBACK &processor) :
                    processor(& processor ){}

    bool process() const{
        // lots of code here,
        // call processor
        processor->operator()(123);

        return true;
    }

    CALLBACK    *processor;
};
```

Comment: In this solution though, `process` is always const regardless of whether `CALLBACK::operator()` is. There is a real solution, it's pretty straightforward, I'll post it shortly.